# How would I draw a liquid metal looking mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm wondering what tools or processes I could use to create a free-flowing, liquid metal-looking mesh similar to the pictures below. I've been trying for hours but I can't seem to find a way to create these really cool flowing shapes. Can anyone give me advice on how I would do this?

[image: Example of free flowing mesh]
[image: Example 2 of free flowing mesh]

Comment: Joey Carlino did a tutorial a while ago which produces something similar using geometry nodes [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udGBqnH9KxA) which might help.

Comment: Thanks so much that's exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Good news! It's sometimes useful having a good memory! :^)

Comment: In the upcoming Blender 3.5 version, you can use the *Blur Attribute* node to smooth the mesh instead of using this 100-node cluster that is shown in the tutorial.

Comment: In the current version of blender, you can also just add a smooth modifier to the Bezier curve and it has the exact same effect, it's just much easier to control the degree of smoothing and toggle the smoothing in certain views if it's becoming too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try a *Bezier Curve* with a *Geometry Nodes* and a *Smooth* modifier.

With the *Draw* tool **(1)** you can create the curve's shape. Adjust the *Radius* of the selected control points in the side panel **(2)**. Add the modifiers and adjust the settings to your needs **(3)**.

The curve on the right uses 100 *Set Position* nodes as shown in Joey Carlino's tutorial "[Blender NEEDS to add this smooth geometry node!](https://youtu.be/udGBqnH9KxA)". But as suggested by *Sam Jakes*, you can use a *Smooth* modifier that does the same job. 
In Blender 3.5 this smooth geometry node is available. It's called the *Blur Attribute* node and can be used to smooth the mesh curves with only one single *Set Position* node.

[image: screenshot]