# Can someone point me towards videos that can help me learn how to model the attached image?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I would like to learn how to model objects that look like they are melting, like the attached image. I have had a hard time finding any resources on how to do this. Can someone point me towards some resources, ideally free videos, that could help me learn? I am a blender novice but use Fusion 360 quite a bit.

[image: Text]

Comment: try https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=model+jelly+in+blender

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Also Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: maybe use fluid and enable the viscosity?

Comment: Or you use curves + GN, like in this question [How would I draw a liquid metal looking mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282497/how-would-i-draw-a-liquid-metal-looking-mesh). -- [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ6O3.jpg)